why images in dataset for face recognition are put into separate folders?
All the datasets for the  face recognition  I have come across so far, use the structure that is described in this question: Face dataset organized by folder
(The images of the same object are stored in thу folder that is into the root folder for the dataset images)
Is there a reason for that? For me it would be easier to include identifiers of certain length  into the images' names and store everything in one folder. Would that be ok?
Or it is specifically for names, because they have different length?
